# Constant used before being initialzed

Tags: swift

```
let errorCodestring : String?

if let theError = errorCodestring {
    print(theError)
}
```

In the above code Xcode throws the error:

> constant 'errorCodestring'being used before being initialized

What is wrong in the code and how to clear the error?

Comment: Please [search on an error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+constant+being+used+before+being+initialized) before posting.

Comment: @rmaddy: Well, it *is* a bit tricky, because you would not get an error with `var errorCodestring : String?`. Optional *variables* are implicitly initialized, but not optional constants.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the constant before using it.

```
let errorCodestring : String? = nil
```